# Socket.IO CPP client example (usage of std::bind)

Tags: c++, qt, socket.io

I'm trying to follow [this](http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-cpp/#setting-up-the-socket) guide to learn how to use Socket.IO CPP client on QT. What I don't understand is one of these lines:

```
auto onm = std::bind(onMessage, _1, _2, _3, _4);
h.socket()->on("message", onm);
```

Which is supposed to call this function:

```
void OnNewMessage(std::string const& name,message::ptr const& data,bool hasAck,message::ptr &ack_resp)
```

I understand that `std::bind(&MainWindow::OnNewMessage` is the name of the function and `_1,_2,_3,_4` are the `std::placeholder` objects but what I fail to understand is why the second argument `this` is passed.

**UPDATE**: 
I tinkered with the code a bit, moved the `onNewMessage` method outside in global scope(updated the code above). I ran into this error:

```
no matching function for call to 
'sio::socket::on(const char [8], std::_Bind<void (*(std::_Placeholder<1>, 
std::_Placeholder<2>, std::_Placeholder<3>, std::_Placeholder<4>)
)(const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>&, 
const std::shared_ptr<sio::message>&, bool, std::shared_ptr<sio::message>&)>&)'
 h.socket()->on("message", onm);
                              ^
```

So I checked the method declaration of `on`:

```
void socket::on(std::string const& event_name,event_listener_aux const& func)
```

And here is the declaration of `event _listener_aux` in a separate header file in class `socket` itself:

```
typedef std::function<void(const std::string& name,message::ptr const& message,bool need_ack, message::list& ack_message)> event_listener_aux;
```

TIA

Comment: Your issue has nothing to do with socket programming, but how `std::bind` is supposed to be used when calling a non-static member function.  If you changed the title of your post, you would have certainly received an answer much sooner.

Comment: See the [documentation and example program](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I saw the example program and they do it without classes for `f1`. That's what confuses me..

Comment: Did you see the `Foo` example?

Comment: Reason for downvote?

Answer (score 4):

`this` needs to be passed to `std::bind` for non-static member class functions, so the code knows which class's method needs to be called.

In this case `this` is the current class, but you could have another class's pointer and it would call its `OnNewMessage` function.

Comment: I saw the doc of `std::bind` here http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind and they do it without classes.. This is what confuses me

Comment: @AkashAggarwal Are you sure you're reading the example program carefully?  There is a clear example there (look at `// bind to a pointer to member function`)

Comment: @AkashAggarwal std::bind with member class function is showcased there with `struct Foo`. For pointer to member functions you need to pass the pointer to the class itself so code knows which class's function needs to be called. I have clarified my answer a bit.

Comment: So if you are using classes, you need the pointer to the class in which the bind function is being called, and if you aren't using classes then you don't need to do this.. right?

Comment: @AkashAggarwal The OnNewMessage is a non-static member function.  It can only be called by providing the object to be called on.  Even if you weren't using `std::bind` and instead did the old-fashioned "call to member function via pointer", you need to provide the object.  So yes, you must provide the object, else it could never work.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie and tambre, Thank you both, I will hit this approach in sometime :)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie and tambre, can you please look into the updated question? I ran into this problem I fail to understand.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal Could you please post the code for the new std::bind?

Comment: It's the first line of the question's first code block.

Comment: I'm marking this as unanswered so that it can grab someone else's attention too. I hope you don't mind that.

Comment: @AkashAggarwal Could you post a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @tambre You'll have to clone this repo for it: https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-cpp
And also you will need to install boost

Comment: @tambre If you have QT I can share away my test project right away with you.